# How to handle Dates as long numbers

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to store Dates on my nodes on the database. I am loading data using webadmin and the csv importer, my problem is that data is saved as string and i need it to be long, i have found some methods to cast some types like toInt() but there is no equivalent for long type.

I have a node that contains two date fields, ArrivalDate and DepartureDate, it is a long number in the csv file but once the query is executed in neo4j the field is stored as a string. The problem is that i cannot make a query to compare Dates since they are strings, a sample query i want to run is like this:

```
match(p:Person)--(s:Stay)
where (s.ArrivalDate)<=634924360000000000 and s.DepartureDate>=634924360000000000)
```

So i would get all the people staying in that Date.

I have done some research, and also asked before here, maybe the question was not that good explained.

For references: i am using the webadmin to load csv files for the bulk load but then my app is in c# and i am using neo4jclient to work with the DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neo4j 2.1 (which is about to release rather soon) has a Cypher command `LOAD CSV`. You can use `toInt` function to convert a string to a numeric value during import. Example:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:/mnt/teamcity-work/42cff4ac2707ec23/target/community/cypher/docs/cypher-docs/target/docs/dev/ql/load-csv/csv-files/file.csv'
  AS line
CREATE (:Artist { name: line.Name, year: toInt(line.Year)})
```

Comment: Thanks, i knew it i am already using 2.1 millestone for the LOAD CSV. But what i have are not integers, it is the date converted to a Long done by the DateTime object in c#. So i am asking for something like toLong function.

Comment: It is only called toInt but handles longs, "int" means integer values. I.e. whole numbers.